# XCode Instruments - find a line where code is leaking

Tags: xcode, cocoa, memory-leaks, instruments

Once a leak is detected in 4.3.2, is there a way to have it take you the line of code where it's happening? In documentation it says:

To locate leaking memory . . .

1. Open the Leaks instrument.
2. Choose your app from the Choose Target pop-up menu.
3. Click the Record button.
4. Exercise your app to execute code, and click the Stop button when leaks are displayed.
5. Click any leaked object that is identified in the Detail pane.
6. Within the Extended Detail pane, double-click an instruction from your code.
7. **Click the Xcode icon in the Detail pane to open that code in Xcode.**

When I double-click on an object under Extended Detail, it does not open the code, it opens a window with something like: `+0x30    testq                          %rax, %rax`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you double-clicked a function in the call stack in the extended detailed view, was the function a function you wrote? If you double-click a function you didn't write, such as a method from the Cocoa framework, you will get assembly language instructions like the one you listed in your question. You have to double-click a function you wrote for Instruments to display your code.

The call tree view in Instruments makes it easier to find the areas of your code that leak memory. Choose Call Tree from the jump bar. On the left side of the window is a Call Tree section with a series of checkboxes. Selecting the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes makes it easier to find your code in the call tree. Double-click one of your functions in the call tree to open the source view, which will show you the lines of code that allocated the leaked memory.

Comment: thank, looks like it was not one of my functions. I did as you said with checkbooks and turned off Sys Libraries, I only got one leak listed with symbol name "start"... hm, go figure what code is causing it. Now, when I choose Leaks from dropdown, the leaked object is one of my classes, and "responsible frame" is -[NSCustomObject nibInstantiate] - which I don't know that that is...

Comment: Ok, I fixed the leak - it was to do with initiation of a class in MainMenu.xib, the phrase "start" was a clue. Fingers crossed I won't see it again.

Comment: I'm able to see the tree, however the calls show my app name, and some memory address. What else does instruments need to be able to link back to the code?

Comment: @Efren Instruments may be having trouble finding your dSYM file that contains the function names. In Instruments choose Instrument > Call Tree Data Mining > Locate dSYM. The dSYM file is usually located in the same directory as the application bundle of the release version of your project.

Comment: Thanks @Mark , it seems to complain with unmatched UUID, could it be due to using cocoapods?

Comment: @Efren I don't use Cocoapods so I can't tell you if that's the problem. I know other people have asked questions here about Instruments showing memory addresses instead of function names. Search for those questions. If none of those questions help you, ask a new question.